# OpenDJ REST returns the same date in two different ways

Tags: rest, ldap, opendj

Organization class has a creation date and my custom fields validFrom and validTo date. The dates should be the same format, but the result looks like this

```
...
"validFrom" : "201502050000+0100",
"created" : "2015-02-13T09:58:24Z"
...
```

validFrom is defined just like the createTimeStamp in openDJ

```
( 2.25.1.1.3.0.0.0.0.0.0
NAME 'validFrom'
EQUALITY generalizedTimeMatch
ORDERING generalizedTimeOrderingMatch
SINGLE-VALUE
SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )
```

I looked to the `http-config.json` and found nothing suspicious

Answer (score 0):

The only think I can think of would be that the value is not a valid GeneralizedTime (i.e. expressed in Zulu time).